Laravel/Dusk-Tests: keys() not working (e.g. ARROW_DOWN, ENTER, ..)
I'm kind of new to Laravel and Dusk-Tests and encountering issues with the Laravel\Dusk\Browser keys()-method. It looks like, that the sent commands are ignored by Chrome. This is the code:
$browser->visit('/index')
    ->assertSee('secret phrase')
    ->pause(300)
    ->click('#selector')
    ->pause(1000)
    ->keys('#selector', [
        WebDriverKeys::DOWN,
        WebDriverKeys::DOWN,
        WebDriverKeys::ENTER,
    ])

What I try to do is to select the second element of a <select>-field. While click() works and opens the dropdown, the keys() simply does nothing.
I'm wondering if this maybe related to me using a Mac (macOS 14.7) or with the current Chrome or Chromedriver (129.0.6668.58)
Thanks for your help!
I've setup a plain Laravel 11 project with a fresh Dusk installation and a sample page. The problem remains. Also tried to Debug the communication between Dusk and the Chromedriver. I can see, that the commands should be sent, but yeah. Nothing happens when I watch how Chrome is remotely controlled by the test.

the correct way to use the method keys wil be like ->keys('#selector', [{ARROW_DOWN},{ARROW_DOWN}, {ENTER}]) i am pretty sure this is the way to do it if it doesnt work try it without capitals and try it without setting the down and enter inside an array but just comma seperatet

Hey and thanks for your help! When I write it this I get an Error: syntax error, unexpected token "{" and my IDE says that Curly brace access syntax is deprecated since PHP 7.4. In the manual they use ['{ARROW_DOWN}'] which doesn't make a difference for me.
The syntax I used I found in existing tests that work in the CI and most likely on Windows. Looks like this may really be a mac issue?

there seem to be a similair issue like this a while ago link what seems to be different between his code and yours is probably that you seem to set the keys inside an array this syntax used for pressing text while the first variablie is hold down. a mistake on my part is that i gave you the wrong syntax sice { might be depricated since 7.4 it is still used in the laravel framwork 11. the corrected syntax is '{ARROW_DOWN}' the diffrence is that you new upload it as text and laravel recognizes it as an key and wil search the key. next comment

inside the Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverKeys this can be found on webdriver_keys this is probably the correct way to use it as explained in laravel-docs and then keys. so if i am correct the right syntax wil be like ->keys('#selector', '{ARROW_DOWN}', '{ARROW_DOWN}', '{ENTER}', ) i hope this is exactly what you need. it isnt a mac issue since code within the laravel framework works the same on mac as on windows by my knowledge. @Torsten Schmitz

@TortenSchmitz is the issue you had resolved with the information given

Sorry for the delay @oelimoe, was on vacation last week. I just checked your suggestion and cross-checked with the docs. Unfortunately it's still the same. Why I think this might be a Mac/Chromedriver issue: Besides this abstract code, it's initially coming from an existing project, that build in the CI with this code. It only fails on my Mac and only the keys() method. click(), type() and others work as expected. Looks like Dusk/Laravel process the info (and fails with wrong selectors or non-existing keys as expected), but valid commands are not received in the Chrome performing this tasks.

i just went over everything there was to find u believe and i dont know how to fix it i am currently at a los the only thing i could find was an old kind of simalair issue but is more a work arround workaround my opoligies i couldnt be more of help

@oelimoe no worries, thanks for your support anyways!

Hey, just for anyone who follows this: I just ran that exact same code within a VM (Ubuntu 24.04, ARM, PHP 8.3, Chromedriver 129.0.6668.89, Chromium Browser) and the code works as expected.

i know you resolved it with using an VM but i have found something that might resolve this for once that is:
macOS may block or restrict certain system-level actions such as keyboard interactions, especially when automated testing tools are being used.
Solution: Check System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy and ensure that the terminal or the browser has permission to simulate keyboard input.
